# How to get Longitude and Latitude for each pixel in an image using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, cluster-analysis

I need to locate the areas in the satellite image based on its color. I can cluster the areas based on color using Matlab, but I'm not able to identify the spatial location. Please assist me how to identify the longitude latitude of those areas using Matlab

```
<i>
veg= imread('vegimg3.png');
imshow(veg), title('Vegitation in Kolleru');
        cform = makecform('srgb2lab');
    newveg = applycform(veg,cform);
    ab = double(newveg(:,:,2:3));
    nrows = size(ab,1);
    ncols = size(ab,2);
    disp(nrows);
    disp(ncols);
    ab = reshape(ab,nrows*ncols,2);
    nColors = 6;
    % repeat the clustering 3 times to avoid local minima
    [cluster_idx cluster_center] = kmeans(ab,nColors,'distance','sqEuclidean','replicates',3);
    pixel_labels = reshape(cluster_idx,nrows,ncols);
    %figure, imshow(pixel_labels,[]), title('image labeled by cluster index');
    segmented_images = cell(1,3);
    rgb_label = repmat(pixel_labels,[1 1 3]);

    for k = 1:nColors
        color = he;
        color(rgb_label ~= k) = 0;
        segmented_images{k} = color;
        imtool(segmented_images{k}), title('objects in cluster'+k);
    end
</i>
```

$ here i can able to cluster the image by color But i need longitude latitude info of each pixel

Comment: That's impossible to answer; we need much more information about the image. Like, at what altitude was it taken, under what angle, of what patch of the Earth, etc. Do you happen to know the lat/lon of the corners of the image? Or of any other location in the image?

Comment: Try to locate on your image some well-known geographic features or objects with known coordinates (you need at least three, but the more the better) and then you can interpolate coordinates for whole image. Otherwise with the information you provided the problem seems unsolvable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *unique* mapping of pixels to geographic coordinates.

This depends on how your image was taken, but we don't have that information. You're supposed to have it.

You may want to read a good book on geographic coordinates. This is pretty hard matter, because there are very different coordinate systems. There isn't even just *one* latitude and longitude, but there are **hundreds of coordinate systems**, and your coordinates will vary more or less whether you are using a WGS84 earth model or some older model.

As is, **your question cannot be answered**. Once you have understood the basics *and* obtained the necessary metadata, you could go to GIS.StackExchange and ask for more detailed help there. But again: as is, they won't be able to answer your question either. Because it's missing required information.